# angularjs templates not hiding div from route

Tags: angularjs

It's two page user registeration process depending on the role the second page could be different but  the first page will always remain the same. what I want I that user can go forward and backwards on both screens with persistent data. I trying a static page at start and then hide it and add the second template from route.

This is my angular app controller.

```
app.controller('addlandlordController' , function($scope , $http , $route ,API_URL ,  $routeParams , uploadService ){
$scope.API_URL = API_URL;
$scope.landVisible = true;
$scope.IsVisible = true;

  if( $routeParams.test)
  {  
    scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.IsVisible = false;
    });
    alert( $routeParams.test);
  }

$scope.adduser = function($route){
         var data = $.param({
                fName: $scope.firstName,
                lName: $scope.lastName,
                role: 'landlord',
                email: $scope.email,
                linkId: $scope.linkId,
                password: $scope.password,
            });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.post(API_URL + 'user' ,  data , config)
           .then(
               function(response){
                    //$scope.IsVisible = false;
                    //alert('success');
               }, 
               function(response){
                 // failure callback
                 alert('fail');
               }
            );
    }
});
```

I have a div in html like this,.

```
<div id="content" class="container1" ng-controller='addlandlordController' >
<div ng-show = "IsVisible">
```

And following is my route in config,.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){    
            $routeProvider.when('/landlord' , {
                templateUrl : 'template/addlandlord.html',
                controller  : 'addlandlordController',
                 resolve: {
                                test: function ($route) { $route.current.params.test = true; }
                          }
            })
        });
```

What I want is that when the user click on the following button.

```
 <a href='#/landlord'> <button  ng-click="adduser()" class="btn btn-info btn-lg signup-btn-land btn-size">Create an Account</button></a>
```

On click that button #/landlord will be added to the url and the route config code will run and add the other template in ng-view which is happening. Now next step is to hide the old div above in such a way that when user go back one sten only the previous code should show and when user goes again into the next screen only the next template should be visible and mean while data should remain same for the both views.

Issues I am facing is

1. Css is for template view is missing although the css files are already in the commen header. But appears when a place css in the style within template.
2. if I hide the first div in the response of adduser then if user go back it still hidden. it doesn't appears unless I refresh the page.

But if went to hide it through route config the value turn false but div never hides.

Comment: If my approach is wrong you can suggest your method to show new template and hide existing div,.

Comment: could you provide pluncker? And when you click does the alert('success'); triggers?

Comment: yes alert apears with correct value,,., but scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.IsVisible = false;
    }); this statement doesn't work

Comment: $scope.IsVisible = false; works without apply but still doesn't hide but value is changed to false ,.

Comment: but if use it here function(response){
                    $scope.IsVisible = false;
               },  then it works

Comment: You have some mess with app logic. When you click add user, post request will be fired and when you receive response, then your callback will be executed (in your case $scope.IsVisible should be set as false. $scope.Apply will not fired because you do not change any state (as I can see from your code) The main question is why div not hides after post.  Please, try next code: in controller define $scope.model = {isVisible:true}; In post callback try $scope.model.isVisible = fase; In Html type <div data-ng-show="model.isVisible">TEST</div>

Comment: It's working in the post code,., it hides the div if place the code in post response ,., my problem there is if user press back button of the browser then that div agian should show up which it doesn't,.,

Comment: Let me check. You want to get next behavior. When user comes FIRST TIME he should see the div. When he pressed BACK you want to reload your page with controller and hide your div if it was hidden before?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
  scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.IsVisible = false;
    });
```

You are using $apply on scope, but not in $scope.

And $applyAsync is preferable method to trigger digest without risking of error "$digest already in progress"

$applyAsync example:

```
$element.on('click', ()=>{
             $scope.model.testValue = 'I have been updated not from angular circle';
             $scope.$applyAsync();
});
```

[Link to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

[Nice article to read](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2751-scope-applyasync-vs-scope-evalasync-in-angularjs-1-3.htm)

Comment: brother   $scope.$applyAsync(); didn't work for me div is not hiding,.,

Comment: can you suggest any other method for hiding the old div and showing new template .,.,